# Dragging rectangle bigger than item itself using QGrahicsRectItem

Tags: qt, draggable, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a problem with a `QGrahicsRectItem` in a `QGraphicsScene`. What I would like is to be able to move the item with mouse. But the problem is that in my case, the dragging rectangle is bigger than the item itself.

Here is the code that I use:

```
class Test: public QGraphicsView
{
    public:
    Test();

    private:
    virtual void resizeEvent (QResizeEvent * event);
    QGraphicsScene* m_pScene;
};

Test::Test()
{
    m_pScene = new QGraphicsScene();
    setScene(m_pScene);

    m_pScene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        QGraphicsRectItem * pItem = new QGraphicsRectItem();
        pItem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
        pItem->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(190, 100, 100)));
        pItem->setRect(QRectF(10*i, 10, 5, 80.f));
        pItem->setCursor(Qt::SizeAllCursor);
        m_pScene->addItem(pItem);
    }


    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

    resize(600, 200);
    fitInView(scene()->sceneRect());
    show();
}

void Test::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event)
{
    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
    fitInView(scene()->sceneRect());
}
```

So when I run my program I have this window, and I can drag items. All seems OK.

[image: screen1]

But if I look closer the dragging zone is bigger than the item itself. (see the blue rectangle on following screenshot) The blue rectangle means that If I move the mouse in this rectangle, the cursor changes, and I can drag the item.

[image: screen2]

I have the feeling that the problem is related to the “fitInView(scene()->sceneRect());” line. If I remove it, then it works.
If I add a ‘scale(5,1)’ for example, there is the same problem.

Do you have an idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: What happens if you add KeepAspectRatio to fitInView call? Does it still have the wrong drag rect? It looks like the paint rect and drag rect are somehow out of sync after the transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you hit this bug: http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17985

What happens is Qt uses a scene rectangle that is 1x1 in size to test if items are under the cursor. In your (and my) case, 1 unit in the scene is larger than 1 pixel on screen. So the 1x1 rectangle covers more than 1 pixel from the cursor, and touches items that are not under the cursor.

I have submitted a fix/merge request. You can modify your Qt source to make it work for now.have

Comment: Thanks for help! So it was a bug in QT, I could search for a long time. QT is usually so stable that I didn't imagined thath it oculd be a bug :) Unfortunaltely I had no time, and had to find a solution, so I created my own GraphicsView, GraphicsScene and GraphicsItem, with my own selection, move, resize algorithms :(

Comment: I find that it's more than just one bug in one spot. Through out graphics view/scene, it's using 1x1 square for point test. QGraphicsScene and its support classes actually have special code for testing a point in an item. Somehow no one is using it. Using a rectangle in place a mathematically zero size point, however small the rectangle it is, is bound to cause errors.